# Python script lost while saving/running

Tags: python, spyder

Today I've been running (by using F5) code I wrote yesterday a few times. After I copied some code from a website `fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()`. This was all I added, but when I wanted to run the code again using F5, the entire script disappered and was replaced by what was in my ctrl+c.

How do I recover my lost code?

Thanks

Comment: I know this sound hard, but you either have a backup of the code or a lesson learned. *(Might be worse a try: If the window is still open `Ctrl` + `Z` could help.)*

Comment: Yeah, `Ctrl+Z` didn't work. How does one backup code better though? All I did was add two lines of code (same line two places) and run the program again.

Do you have two seperate file names for every file?

Comment: This is not the right place to discuss backup strategies. There here are two things to keep in mind: a backup **seems** to be unimportant until needed and the right strategy depends totally on **your** requirements and resources.